# Adding a variable inside VLookUp

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem with a vlookup function. First code shows that `VLOOKUP` know what is `"TempArg'17"`, but now I want to change it this text to string and write it inside `VLOOKUP`, so I created a string `temp`.

```
Dim temp As String
Dim num As Int
num = 17

temp = "TempArg" + "'" + Cstr(num)
```

Here is the old code that works:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP([@[" & Chr(10) & "Stevilka]],'TempArg''17'!C[-16]:C[-17],2,FALSE)"
```

And here is the code that I want to change and that doesn't work:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP([@[" & Chr(10) & "Stevilka]],'" & temp & "'!C[-16]:C[-17],2,FALSE)"
```

This is what I get.

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a missing single quote `'`.

Change following line:

```
temp = "TempArg" + "'" + CStr(num)
```

to

```
temp = "TempArg" + "''" + CStr(num)
```

or even better

```
temp = "TempArg''" & CStr(num)
```

Also with `Dim num As Int` this won't run.

Should be `Dim num As Integer` instead, but I guess this is a typo...

Comment: @rivaq45: don't forget to accept the answer if it helped. By you accepting the answer, it closes the query and rewards MatSnow with appropriate points

Comment: It works, thanks. But now I have the other problem. If I print out what is in temp, I get "TempArg''17" and not "TempArg'17". What should I do?

Comment: @rivaq45 This is the expected result, so I don't understand what you mean exactly by `What should I do`? But, as this seems to be a different problem, I suggest to create a new question with appropriate details what you're trying to achieve and mark this question as answered.