# Print a variable

Tags: vba, excel

At first please check this thread -> [Adding a variable inside VLookUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666764/adding-a-variable-inside-vlookup#comment86345633_49667024)

Still doesn't work..

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Please remove the `vb.net` tag as this is a `vba` question. It is still not clear what you mean. Why do you expect something different on the label than is stored in the variable?

Comment: Are you trying to print this in a form label? If so, just use replace (i.e. `Me.MyLabel.Caption = Replace(temp, "''", "'")`)

Comment: I have sheets with month names as "TempJan'17, TempFeb'17"... And I want to print in label which sheet is in use.

Comment: In which label?  I think you're mixing up some terms. Can you include a screen shot showing what you're trying to do?

Comment: Check the question again please.

Comment: @rivaq45 I read the question repeatedly, it's very hard to understand.  Even worse when you add a bunch of code and say "whats wrong?"  Please see [ask] as well as [help/on-topic] and especially [mcve] re: your examples.

Comment: Almost everything works fine just the problem is that when I print to label I get for example "TempDec''17" but I should get "TempDec'17" what is the correct name of the sheet. This is all what I want.

Comment: I think you are referring to sheet names as **Label**. I've read through your query again but unfortunately it's not clear as to: where in your code the problem is? (although there are few I can see but I don't think they are related to your question). Second, what the actual problem is?. I know you've tried to explain but I still don't get it. I suspect that `Replace` is your answer but can't be sure without understanding the question. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the a different value for the `temp`-variable and the `Label`:

```
temp = "Temp" + MonthNameUpper + "''" + CStr(MonthView1.Year - 2000)
Label3 = "Temp" + MonthNameUpper + "'" + CStr(MonthView1.Year - 2000)
```

Comment: is this the only way? Is it professional to do that? I was thinking about to have all in one variable.

Comment: No, it's not the only way. There's almost always more than one solution for a problem. But if this is just to show a text on a label then I don't see any problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try this line **`temp = "Temp" + MonthNameUpper + "'" + CStr(MonthView1.Year - 2000)`**  instead `temp = "Temp" + MonthNameUpper + "''" + CStr(MonthView1.Year - 2000)`

Comment: Not sure if that would work because OP is using **`temp`** in `VLookUp` in his code below that line where he needs the *''* in **`temp`**

Comment: Yes your correct that's why he is getting error. Hope now he wont!

Comment: Linga thanks but it doesn't work with this. I get this error: Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: in which line your getting it?